# Missing LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers, mapcontrol

I was wondering if there is a `LayerSwitcher` control in OpenLayers 3?

I read that ol3 is a complete rewrite. But I can't seem to find the equivalent of `LayerSwitcher` from http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.html. I don't see how one can turn on and off layers without this control. Is `LayerSwitcher` renamed to something else, missing or is the documentation incomplete?

If OpenLayers3 does not have `LayerSwitcher`, does anyone know of an example that implements a custom control like the old LayerSwitcher?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question was asked on Twitter recently https://twitter.com/RemiBovard/status/525028570780139520

If you follow the answer, at the moment, integrating layer switcher in the core is not the priority but there is an available component at https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher

You can also take a look on ["The book of OpenLayers" samples](https://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/) (by @acanimal) for some custom legend implementations.

Answer (score 1):

there is a project on github running but it is in a very early stage. It is using extjs for the tree panel. check it here [extjs_ol3_layercontrol](https://github.com/ptsagkis/extjs_ol3_layercontrol/)

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to have a look [at this extension](http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.switcher.html) which implements a layer switching control with many useful additional features such as toggling whole layer groups on and off, controlling layer visibility via a slider and switching the drawing order of the layers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for OL 3+ versions the current one I have created on ol 6+ but will work with 3+ versions as well with minor tweaks.
Please find this [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol6-layer-switcher-7q0c6).

It's a small example to create ol library style layer switcher which can be used as individual control or you can directly utilize interaction where ever you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can also look for the layer-switcher JavaScript which has been implemented for Openlayers v3.x in this example [Closest Distance Map](http://geospatialearth.in/ol3/main).

You can also download it and implement in your project.