# OpenLayers 3 / LayerSwitcher: how to link each layer with its legend?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I can manage my layers by the LayerSwitcher panel. The legend is created by HTML, and I post it on the site by:

```
Document.getElementById ("legend") style.display = "block";
```

What I want: When I check or I uncheck the layer, its legend will appear or disappear. How can I do that?

```
 var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
    tipLabel: 'Légende' // Optional label for button

 });

  map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

Comment: LayerSwitcher was in OL2 but is not currently supported in OL3.  See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/missing-layerswitcher-in-openlayers3

Comment: this question is asked in 2 years ago, and i use ol3 in the development of my site. how can i add a screenshot to show you?

Comment: The question may be two years old, but the latest [OL3 docs v3.20.0](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html) still don't seem to have a layerswitcher control

Comment: thank you, may be what I use it is other than layerswitcher.