# Making only one of many layers visible using OpenLayers with GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers, layers, select

[image]

I'm working on a fairly straightforward project, the idea is that I have code linked to a geoserver hosting a bunch of layers, the idea is that the user may select to view only a single layer out of the bunch using the option down there, problem is I don't know how to do that.

I've implemented the interface and the layers are connected to geoserver, but they all appear on top of one another, I don't know how to make it so only the selected one appears.

Checked this demo from openlayers, http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html?q=layers but it wasn't very helpful, its the same idea, but the way it displays layers is different, and I don't know what to do.

This is my code

```
> <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
        .map {
            height: 600px;
            width:100%;
            background:#F9EECF;
            border:1px dotted black
        } 
        </style>
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2></h2>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <div id="mouse-position"></div>
        <form class="form">
        <label>Capa </label>
      <select id="format">
        <option value="rios_dobles">Rios Dobles </option>
        <option value="rios_simples">Rios Simples</option>  
        <option value="lagos_lagunas">Lagos Lagunas</option>
        <option value="vias">Vias</option>
        <option value="limite_parroquial" selected>Limite Parroquial</option>
        <option value="basicos">Basicos</option>
        <option value="Centros_Poblados">Centros Poblados</option>
        <option value="Aptitud_final">Aptitud Final</option>
        <option value="uso_final">Uso Final</option>
      </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#319FD3',
                    width: 1
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#000'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff',
                        width: 3
                    })
                })
            });

            var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                projection: 'EPSG:32617',
                 // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
                // be placed within the map.
                className: 'custom-mouse-position',
                target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
                undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
            });

            var format = 'image/png';

            var limites = new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    ratio: 1,
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gis2017/wms',
                    params: {'FORMAT': format,
                        'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        STYLES: '',
                        LAYERS: 'gis2017:limite_parroquial',
                    }
                })
            });

            var lagos = new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    ratio: 1,
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gis2017/wms',
                    params: {'FORMAT': format,
                        'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        STYLES: '',
                        LAYERS: 'gis2017:lagos_lagunas',
                    }
                })
            });

            var vias = new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    ratio: 1,
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gis2017/wms',
                    params: {'FORMAT': format,
                        'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        STYLES: '',
                        LAYERS: 'gis2017:vias',
                    }
                })
            });

            var riosDobles = new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    ratio: 1,
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gis2017/wms',
                    params: {'FORMAT': format,
                        'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        STYLES: '',
                        LAYERS: 'gis2017:rios_dobles',
                    }
                })
            });

            var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
                code: 'EPSG:32617',
                units: 'm',
                axisOrientation: 'neu'
            });


            var map = new ol.Map({
                controls: ol.control.defaults({
                    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                        collapsible: false
                    })
                }).extend([mousePositionControl]),

                target: 'map',

                layers: [
                    limites,
                    lagos,
                    vias,
                    riosDobles
                ],
                view: new ol.View({
                    projection: projection
                })
            });

            var bounds = [829997.713005126, 17467.5016493353,
                855074.885060481, 48128.6231498908];
            map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());

            // a normal select interaction to handle click
            //var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
            //map.addInteraction(select);

            var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
                condition: ol.events.condition.click
            });

            map.addInteraction(selectClick); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need a layer switcher. Perhaps this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/missing-layerswitcher-in-openlayers3

Comment: Check `setVisible` on layer. as the sample does.

Comment: but how? As I mentioned the codes are so different that I don't see how to use it.